# Recursively search for files

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I am trying to find all files by passing a directory name in all sub directories meaning the process is recursive here is my code

```
myrecursive() {
  if [ -f $1 ]; then 
    echo $1
  elif [ -d $1 ]; then
    for i in $(ls $1); do
      if [ -f $1 ]; then
        echo $i 
      else
        myrecursive $i
      fi
    done
  else
    echo " sorry"
  fi
}
myrecursive $1
```

However when I pass directory with another directory I get 2 times sorry,where is my mistake?

Comment: Why not just utilise the find command?

Comment: I am trying to implement it myself ,I know find can do the work but that is not the point .

Answer (score 2):

The goal that you are trying to achieve could be simply done by using [`find`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html) command:

```
# will search for all files recursively in current directory 
find . * -exec echo {} \;

# will search for all *.txt file recursively in current directory 
find . -name "*.txt" -exec echo {} \;

# will search for all *.txt file recursively in current directory 
# but depth is limited to 3
find . -name "*.txt" -max-depth 3 -exec echo {} \;
```

See `man find` for manual. [How to run find -exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is quite simple.

The `ls` command will return a list of filenames, but they aren't valid for
recursion.  Use globbing instead.   The loop below simply replaces `$(ls)` with `$1/*`

```
myrecursive() {
  if [ -f $1 ]; then 
    echo $1
  elif [ -d $1 ]; then
    for i in $1/*; do
      if [ -f $1 ]; then
        echo $i
      else
        myrecursive $i
      fi
    done
  else
    echo " sorry"
  fi
}
myrecursive $1
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
myrecursive() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then 
    echo "$1"
  elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
    for i in "$1"/*; do
      if [ -f "$i" ]; then #here now our file is $i
        echo "$i"
      else
        myrecursive "$i"
      fi
    done
  else
    echo " sorry"
  fi
}
myrecursive "$1"
```

Comment: Need double quotes around the variables.